# How to get minimum odd number using functions from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the minimum odd number using python. I used lambda, loops and other methods to get minimum odd number but i was not able to get that using functions. here is my code

```
z= [1,8,-4,-9]

def min_odd(x):
    for i in x:
        if (i%2!=0):
    return min(i)

y = min_odd(z)
print (y)
```

Can some please tell me what i was missing here.

Comment: if you used a `lambda` then you used a function.

Comment: A one liner for you `min(z[z%2!=0])` once you convert z to NumPy array as `z= np.array([1,8,-4,-9])`

Comment: @Bazingaa So in effect it's 2-liner?

Comment: Yeah, you can be technical ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `min()` function expects an iterable like a list which it will then yield the smallest element from.

E.g. `min([1,0,3])` gives `0`.

So if you want to use it, you must create a list (or other iterable) of the odd numbers that you can then pass into it:

```
def min_odd(x):
    odds = []
    for i in x:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            odds.append(i)
    return min(odds)
```

note that we could also use a list-comprehension:

```
def min_odd(x):
    return min([i for i in x if i % 2 != 0])
```

which both work.

---

An alternative method would be to store the current minimum odd value in a variable and update this variable if we come across a smaller odd value:

```
def min_odd(x):
   min_v = float('inf')
   for i in x:
      if i % 2 != 0 and i < min_v:
         min_v = i
   return min_v
```

Comment: Great, Thank you I haven't got that idea and started banging my head on wall

Comment: You don't need to create a list  -- you can create a generator within `min`.

Comment: @erip Yes you can do that too, but in some cases a list comp is faster

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`min([val for val in z if val % 2 != 0])`

Answer (score 3):

It seems your code logics are wrong. First off, you seem to have an indentation error in the return statement. Second off, the min() function requires a collection of items (like an array for example) or a series of arguments to determine the minimum in that series. You can try multiple things.

1. Use another variable to store a temporary minimum. Replace it every time you find a smaller odd value ( for every i in x... if the value is odd and is smaller than the previous odd value, replace it) and have it started with the first odd number you can find.
2. Take all the odd numbers and add them to another array on which you will apply the min function.

Hope this proves useful!

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a generator into the `min()` function:

```
def min_odd(iterable):
    return min(i for i in iterable if i % 2)
```

I didn't write `i % 2 != 0` because any odd number will return 1 which has a Boolean value of True.

I added a parameter to the function that takes the iterable so it can be used for any iterable passed in.

Answer (score 1):

`min` operates on an iterable. `i` is not an iterable in your code; it's the last element of the list.

You can achieve what you want with a filter, though:

```
min(filter(lambda e: e%2 != 0, x))
```